# To training a Decision Tree model, what is the better way to deal with attributes represented by a vector?

Tags: decision-tree, feature-selection

In most of instruction discussing Decision Tree, the attributes are represented by a single value, and then these values are concatenated as a feature vector. It makes sense since normally the attributes are independent to each other.

However, in practice, some attributes can only represented as vector or matrix, for example, a GPS coordinate (x,y) in 2D map.  If x and y are correlative, (nonlinear dependence e.g.), it is not a good a solution to concatenate them with other attributes simply. I wonder if there are some better techniques to deal with them?

thanks